# MySQL Query select all where only one of two options are found

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

`Members` (`member_id`, `member_info`)

`Question_Answers` (`Question_id`, `Answer`)

If there are two questions, I need to find out which member only answered one of the questions, and not both.

I have tried to use `GROUP BY`, but have not gotten the results I am looking for.

Closest I've gotten was with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(qa.question_id), mem.member_id
FROM question_answers qa
LEFT JOIN members mem ON mem.member_id = qa.member_id
```

This gets me the results for questions answered by user, but it includes results where the members answered both questions.

I am looking for advice on how to `SELECT` the member that only answered one of the questions.

EDIT: I have gotten closer, but would like to make it better.

```
    SELECT IF( COUNT( DISTINCT( qa.question_id ) ) = 2, 'TWO', 'ONE' ), mem.member_id, MAX( qa.question_id )
FROM question_answers qa
JOIN members mem ON qa.member_id = mem.member_id
WHERE mem.type = 9
GROUP BY mem.member_id  
ORDER BY `mem`.`member_id` ASC
```

This is a hacky way because the question ID's are currently on 0 and 1, but if anyone has a recommendation on how to return the question_id from the `SELECT IF(` then that would help out a lot.

Comment: I've attempted to edit your post to make it more clear what you are asking for, but I was even a bit confused myself. You've used the alias `rus` in your example query but I do not see a reference to that anywhere so I'm guessing that might be a version of an `Answers` table like I've provided below.

Comment: @Brien Thanks, `rus` alias is because the table is named something else in reality but I was trying to simplify it.

Comment: Don't ask your question with an example ("If there are two questions, I need to find out which member only answered one of the questions, and not both"). What if there is one question, three, four, a thousand? What is the real request? Do you want every user who hasn't answered all questions available (which we find in a question table not shown)? Or all users who have only answered one single question so far? Or is this about two specific questions, i.e. all users who have either answered question A or B, but not both?

Comment: By the way: Do you actually know what a left outer join does? In your first query you are retrieving answers even if they were not given by a member. Does that even make sense? And `DISTINCT` is not a function, so remove the confusing parentheses from that query. `DISTINCT` works on the complete row, i.e. the combination of `qa.question_id` and `mem.member_id` here.

Comment: People want to help, I want to help, its just that there isn't enough information in your question to help you accurately. It's apparent that what is needed is the DDL statements (`CREATE`.. is what we are looking for) for creating **all** the tables involved in this question, a few rows of relevant data in **each** table, and a very clear example of what you expect to see when the correct query is used. Please do not use data like `'aasdflkjasd'`,`'asf23432'`,`'32234234324fdasf'`, etc... because that is hellish to look at and also makes making sense out of the question and answer impossible.

Comment: In my answer below I have the best intention on helping you solve your problem, but its a case where I don't have enough information to help you. It becomes this infinite circular discussion where everyone involved is confused and this Q&A post becomes a nightmare to use/understand in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would have a third table to hold the data of who has answered which questions.

In my example I have called this table `Answered`.

Here is how I would solve this, maybe you can glean some ideas off this example if you don't want to do it this way: [[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/MGJEM39097).

```
SELECT m1.*, qa.*
FROM Members m1
INNER JOIN Answered a ON m1.member_id = a.member_id
INNER JOIN Question_Answers qa ON a.question_id = qa.question_id
WHERE m1.member_id IN (
    SELECT m2.member_id
    FROM Members m2
    INNER JOIN Answered a ON m2.member_id = a.member_id
    INNER JOIN Question_Answers qa ON a.question_id = qa.question_id
    GROUP BY m2.member_id
    HAVING COUNT(m2.member_id) = 1);
```

[image]

Comment: This will also work, select m.*, qa.* , count(distinct a.question_id) as c from Answered a 
inner join Question_Answers qa on qa.question_id=a.question_id 
inner join Members m on m.member_id= a.member_id group by a.member_id having c = 1 ;

Comment: You're right, just is not a way that I would naturally write it coming from a TSQL/SQLServer background. Appears MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that you can use nonaggregated columns or calculations in the `SELECT` list that do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. I personally like explicitly choosing.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I can take some aspects out of it, but I am working with current data so I cannot add a third table to start tracking answers.